# Using variable on chunk function Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I need to use a variable into a method on laravel 4, how can i pass this variable to the method chunk from eloquent?

```
$variableonmethod=array('value1','value2');
PreAlumno::chunk(200, function($prealumnos) {
        foreach ($prealumnos as $pre) {
           //do something with variableonmethod
        }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the array using the use ($var) to achieve your result.

```
$variableonmethod=array('value1','value2');
PreAlumno::chunk(200, function($prealumnos) use ($variableonmethod) {
    foreach ($prealumnos as $pre) {
       //do something with variableonmethod
    }
});
```

Answer (score 22):

If you like only read information

```
$variableonmethod=array('value1','value2');
PreAlumno::chunk(200, function($prealumnos) use ($variableonmethod) {
    echo variableonmethod[0]; // prints `value1`
    variableonmethod[0] = 'Hola';
    echo variableonmethod[0]; // prints `Hola`
    foreach ($prealumnos as $pre) {
       //do something with variableonmethod
    }
});
echo variableonmethod[0]; // prints `value1`
```

But, if you like to read array AND CHANGE THEIR VALUES (check **&** on `use`)

```
$variableonmethod=array('value1','value2');
PreAlumno::chunk(200, function($prealumnos) use (&$variableonmethod) {
    echo variableonmethod[0]; // prints `value1`
    variableonmethod[0] = 'Hola';
    echo variableonmethod[0]; // prints `Hola`
    foreach ($prealumnos as $pre) {
       //do something with variableonmethod
    }
});
echo variableonmethod[0]; // prints `Hola`
```

Comment: great, this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As per your need for accessing the variable within the chunk method that means outside of the scope. In PHP you can use a closure for passing the variable outside of the chunk method scope. Here is an example:

```
$variableonmethod=array('value1','value2');
PreAlumno::chunk(200, function($prealumnos) use ($variableonmethod) {
        foreach ($prealumnos as $pre) {
           //further implementation of your code
        }
});
```